# ERROR: failed to create cluster while running kind create cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster, kind

When I run `kind create cluster` in Ubuntu 20.04 I get this error:

```
Creating cluster "kind" ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.21.1)  
 ✓ Preparing nodes   
 ✓ Writing configuration  
 ✗ Starting control-plane ️ k
ERROR: failed to create cluster: failed to init node with kubeadm: command "docker exec --privileged kind-control-plane kubeadm init --skip-phases=preflight --config=/kind/kubeadm.conf --skip-token-print --v=6" failed with error: exit status 1
```

Complete logs: https://paste.debian.net/1207493/

What can be the reason for this? I cannot find any relevant solution in the docs or existing github issues.

Comment: What is your `$ kind version`?

Comment: kind v0.11.1 go1.16.4 linux/amd64
@KamolHasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. After adjusting the docker memory allocation, the cluster was created successfully

Comment: If you could give some guidelines (like "increase" is generic did you: double, trial and error for memory allocation?  Any heuristic that work for you?) that would great to add

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).